# Linker error 1120 in VC++ 2010 project.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker-errors

I'm doing my first VC++ project and am using the following code. The project has the following files.

Project1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PopulateDB.h"

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{

    PopulateDB x;
    x.calcUpload();


    return 0;
}
```

PopulateDB.h

```
#pragma once
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>

class PopulateDB
{
public:
    int calcUpload(void);
    PopulateDB(void);
    ~PopulateDB(void);

private:

    int updateMA(sql::Connection &);
};
```

PopulateDB.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "PopulateDB.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include "Technical.h"

using namespace std;

int updateMA(sql::Connection& con)
{
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    int i;

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from PriceAMS");

    while(res->next())
    {
        cout << "Symbol " << i << " = " << res->getBlob("Symbol") << endl;
        i++;
    }

    delete stmt;
}

int calcUpload(void)
{
    cout << "Running Connection..." << endl;

    try 
    {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

/* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "nishantd", "mySQLDB%passWord2013"); //we can initialize the user/pass in constructor
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("testMMDB");
        cout << "Looks like it connected..." << endl;

        updateMA(*con);

        delete con;
    }

    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


PopulateDB::PopulateDB(void)
{
}


PopulateDB::~PopulateDB(void)
{
}
```

Technical.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Technical
{
public:

    float StandardMovingAverage(std::vector<float> values);
    float StdDev(std::vector<float> values);
    float Variance(std::vector<float> values);
    int RSI(std::vector<float> values);

    Technical(void);
    ~Technical(void);

};
```

Technical.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Technical.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

float Technical::StandardMovingAverage(vector <float> values)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i < values.size(); i++)
        sum+=values[i];
    return sum/values.size();
}

float Technical::StdDev(vector <float> values)
{
    float E=0;
    float ave = StandardMovingAverage(values); //this function just calculates the mean values
    for(int i=0; i < values.size(); i++)
        E+=(values[i]- ave)*(values[i]- ave);
    return sqrt(1/values.size()*E);
}

float Technical::Variance(vector <float> values)
{
    return StdDev(values)*StdDev(values);
}


Technical::Technical(void)
{
}


Technical::~Technical(void)
{
}
```

I am getting the following error in VC++ 2010. There are warnings which I am currently ignoring

```
1>Project1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall PopulateDB::calcUpload(void)" (?calcUpload@PopulateDB@@QAEHXZ)
1>D:\Project\CPP\Project1\Release\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am trying to resolve this and get my code to work. Its even more frustrating because I suspect I am missing something very basic since I am new to VC++ and the code anyway doesn't do much in its current shape.

Really appreciate all help

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function named `PopulateDB::calcUpload` - a member function of class `PopulateDB`. But you've never actually implemented that function. You did implement a different, standalone, non-member function named `::calcUpload`, but you are not calling it.

In your implementation file, make it

```
int PopulateDB::calcUpload() {...}
```